# Show that the argument form with premises $(p∧t)→...¬s$ and conclusion $q→r$ is valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Stuck on this problem. I want to use the rules of inference to show that the argument form with premises $(p∧t)→(r∨s)$, $q→(u∧t),u→p$, and $¬s$ and conclusion $q→r$ is valid. Would really appreciate if someone can help me solve it and explain which rules they used

Comment: Which rules of inference are you allowed to use?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco all of them

Comment: HINT Try a conditional proof

Comment: @Nev different systems may use different rules (Or rules by different names).  *Which* are yours?

Comment: @GrahamKemp modus ponens, modus tollens, hypothetical syllogism, disjunctive syllogism, rule of proof by case, rule of contradiction, rule of simplification, rule of addition, rule of resolution

Comment: It helps a lot to have an intuitive understanding of the proof before worrying about how to formally write it. Do you see informally why the argument is valid?

Comment: Assume we know q. From q we know u and t. From u we know p. Now we know t and p, which implies r or s. But we know s is false, so r must be true.

Answer (score 0):

$\neg s$  premise $1$

$(p \wedge t) \to (r \lor s)$ premise $2$

$(p \land t) \to r$         based on $1$ and $2$ Disjunctive Syllogism

$q \to (u \land t)$ premise $4$

$q \to r$ (hypothetical syllogism) from $3$ and $4$

Is this answer correct? I am not sure if $(p \land t) == (u \land t)$. Because based on Hypothetical syllogism, $P \to Q$ and $Q \to R \implies P \to R$. In this cause I am taking $(p \land t) == (u \land t) == Q$

Comment: I tried to format your answer using mathjax, please check if it is what you intend it to be.

Answer (score 0):

$
1) (p\land q)\to (r\lor s)   :Premise
$

$
2) \lnot p\lor \lnot t \lor r\lor s :  
$
Logical equivalence of (1)

$
3) s \lor (\lnot p \lor \lnot t \lor r) :
$
Commutative and associative laws on (2)

$
4) \lnot s : Premise
$

$
5) \lnot p \lor (\lnot t \lor r) :
$
Disjunctive syllogism on (3) and (4)

$
6) u \to p : Premise
$

$
7) \lnot u \lor p
$
Logical equivalence of (6)

$
8) p \lor \lnot u :
$
Commutative law on (7)

$
9) \lnot u \lor \lnot t \lor r :
$
Resolution law on (5) and (8)

$
10) \lnot(u \land t) \lor r :
$
De Morgan's law on (9)

$
11) (u \land t) \to r :
$
Logical equivalence of (10)

$
12) q \to (u \land t) :
$
Premise

$
13) q \to r :
$

Hypothetical syllogism on (12) and (11)

Answer (score 0):

$(p∧t)→(r∨s), q→(u∧t), u→p, ¬s \vdash q→r$

$
\begin{array}{11111}
\{1\} & 1. & (p∧t)→(r∨s) & \text{premise} \\
\{2\} & 2. & q→(u∧t) & \text{premise} \\
\{3\} & 3. & u→p & \text{premise} \\
\{4\} & 4. & ¬s & \text{premise} \\
\{5\} & 5. & q & \text{Assumption for Conditional Proof} \\
\{2,5\} & 6. & u∧t & \text{2,5 Modus Ponens} \\
\{2,5\} & 7. & u & \text{6 Conjuntion Elimination} \\
\{2,5\} & 8. & t & \text{6 Conjuntion Elimination} \\
\{2,3,5\} & 9. & p & \text{3,7 Modus Ponens} \\
\{2,3,5\} & 10. & p \wedge t & \text{8,9 Conjunction Introduction} \\
\{1,2,3,5\} & 11. & r \vee s & \text{1,10 Modus Ponens} \\
\{1,2,3,4,5\} & 12. & r & \text{4,11 SI: Disjunctive Syllogism} \\
\{1,2,3,4\} & 13. & q \to r & \text{5,12 Conditional Proof} & \square \\
\end{array}
$